# System.CalloutException: Callout from scheduled Apex not supported

Tags: apex

I have written the below class. However when I schedule the class I get the following error:

> **Callout from scheduled Apex not supported**

```
global class Accenture_Current_Backlog implements Schedulable {

    global void execute(SchedulableContext sc) {

        ApexPages.PageReference report = new ApexPages.PageReference('/00O1a0000039OPy?csv=1');
        Messaging.EmailFileAttachment attachment = new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment();
        attachment.setFileName('Accenture_Current_Backlog.csv');
        attachment.setBody(report.getContent());
        attachment.setContentType('text/csv');
        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage message = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
        message.setFileAttachments(new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment[] { attachment } );
        message.setSubject('Accenture Current Backlog Report');
        message.setPlainTextBody('The report is attached.');
        message.setToAddresses( new String[] { 'abhijit.bhagwat@live.in','abhijit.bhagwat@yahoo.in' } );
        message.setCcAddresses(new String[] { 'abhagwat@qualys.com.com'});
        Messaging.sendEmail( new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { message } );
    }
}
```

Comment: Important context for others looking at this in the future: the `getContent()` method on the 4th line in the execute method (`attachment.setBody(report.getContent());`) has been treated as a callout since API v34.0 (Summer '15)

Answer (score 2):

Write a helper method with `@future` annotation and call it from execute method.

otherwise create a Batch Apex class and implement `Database.AllowsCallouts` interface

```
global class Accenture_Current_Backlog implements Database.Batchable<sObject>, Database.AllowsCallouts
```

Comment: I tried implementing `Database.AllowsCallouts` interface in Schedule job, and that didn't help. `Database.AllowsCallouts` workf only for batch jobs.

Comment: @AlexanderBerehovskiy Yes, you're right. Updated the answer.

Comment: @RohitMourya I have one scheduler apex, one flow, and one apex to make integration, the scheduler calls the flow, and the flow calls the apex of integration, in this case, should give an error of "Callout from scheduled Apex not supported"?